# Use MATLAB to search for the path of an external hard drive plugged into my device?

Tags: matlab, filepath, drive, hard-drive

I am using an external hard drive and I would like to have a few lines in my code, before loading the data from this external hard drive, that runs a search for the hard drive name without me having to change it every time I plug the hard drive into a different device.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you need to filter on a volume name you can use a [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) call to [`wmic`](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm) (e.g. `wmic get volume "Drive Letter","Label"`) and parse the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function [exist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html). You can use it to check if a particular folder exists. It returns '7' if the location exists, otherwise zero.

Example (on my machine I have only C:\ and D:\ disks):

```
 exist 'C:' %output 7
 exist 'D:' %output 7
 exist 'E:' %output 0
```

Thus, you can look for different names and check if they exist.

Some of the custom-written scripts based on `exist` function are available at [Mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1082-getdrives) website.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir` to get files in a location, and test if there's anything there!

```
dirResult = dir('E:\myPath\') % Search for all files within some drive location
if isempty(dirResult)
    warning('No files found in that location!');
else
    % Do stuff
    % Can get all files within your search path using
    dirResult = struct2table(dirResult); % for ease of manipulation
    fileNames = dirResult.name; 
    % Loop over file names etc. to do more stuff...
end
```

If you simply want to check the *existence* of a directory, use `exist`

```
if ~exist( 'E:\myPath', 'dir' )
    warning('No files found in that location!');
else
    % do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using absolute paths I suppose. For example `imread` accepts full path names, so you can use it to load a file located anywhere in your machine, even in an external hard drive.

Alternatively you can use cd function to change your working directory: [cd](https://en.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html)

Comment: I'll look into imread. Do you know if it also works for searching for folders?

Comment: What function will you use for searching for folders? I'm sure that it supports something like full path name.

Comment: Nevermind, if I can find a specific file on the hard drive and grab the path name that is all I need.

Comment: Look at the edit. You can also change the working directory to any folder.